# How do detatch and reattach a x-forwarded ssh-session?

Tags: gnu-screen, xforwarding

i have a linux-server and would like to run linuxdcpp (linux dc++) on it.
for that I need to create a ssh connection with x-forwarding like:

```
ssh user@server -X
```

Then I need something like screen to start a session I can reattach later.

the thing with screen that it does not work. the moment I detach the screen session,  the x-forwarded program stays open and will be terminated the moment I close it.

Is there something I can use for both: screen with x-forwarding?

Answer (score 4):

There are [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove) [hacks](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra), none of which are very satisfying.  The usual solution to this is to run a VNC or NX on the remote machine.